# How to push bunch of data at a time into firebase database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am inserting about `100000` of `record` into firebase databse using `push`,

but i am getting an error like bellow:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

My code as given below:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < unamelist.length; i++) {
        var uname = unamelist[i];

        var Actionref = firebase.database().ref("Actionusers/" + mkey);
        var newData = {
            Actiontype: 3,
            status: true,
            Iscompleted: 0,
            username: uname.toLowerCase(),
            datetime: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }

        Actionref.push(newData,function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error while push Action users from excel: ' + error)
                }
                else{
                    var testActionref = firebase.database().ref("Actionusers/" + mkey);
                    testActionref.once('value').then(function (snap) {
                        var stupdateref1 = firebase.database().ref('Msgtemplate/' + mkey);
                        stupdateref1.update({
                            Rest: snap.numChildren()
                        })
                    })
                }

            })
    }
```

Comment: I don't immediately see what would cause a stack overflow here. Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, from the error, that you could include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx @frank for quik look,

I just Slove my problem By code below:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < unamelist.length; i++) {
        var uname = unamelist[i];
        console.log(uname);

        var Actionref = firebase.database().ref("Actionusers/" + mkey);
        var newData = {
            Actiontype: 3,
            status: true,
            Iscompleted: 0,
            username: uname.toLowerCase(),
            datetime: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }

        Actionref.push(newData)

        if (i == (unamelist.length-1)) {
           Actionref.once('value').then(function (snap) {
            var stupdateref1 = firebase.database().ref('Msgtemplate/' + mkey);
            stupdateref1.update({
                Rest: snap.numChildren()
            })
           })
        }
    }
```

I think when i push data to `Actionusers` every time i was update `Rest` in diffrent node, so that's why numbers of calls gonaa very big in an amount.
TO resolve this i just update `Rest` after complete for for loop and its resolved my issue.